# Draw grid lines using Canvas js logarithmic chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

i have created a chart using canvas js library 
but i am having issue while displaying grid lines on the chart

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title: {
        text: "Axis Y with interval 20"
      },
      axisY:{
        logarithmic : true,
        gridthickness : 1,
        minimum : 10,
        maximum : 101,
     },
      data: [
      {
        type: "line",
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 100, y: 71 },
        { x: 200, y: 55},
        { x: 300, y: 50 },
        { x: 400, y: 65 },
        { x: 500, y: 95 },
        { x: 600, y: 68 },
        { x: 700, y: 28 },
        { x: 800, y: 34 },
        { x: 900, y: 14}
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[this is how i wanted the grid to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7ddc.png)

[this is how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXQJx.png)

anyone know how to properly format the grid lines, i have alse added demo snipped of how my data will look like

Comment: show some code, else this will be delete via downvoting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor grids are not available as of now. However by adding stripLines you can achieve the same as shown below.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
  title: {
    text: "Axis Y with interval 10"
  },
  axisY: {
    logarithmic: true,
    gridThickness: 0,
    tickThickness: 0,
    labelFormatter: function(e) {
      return ""
    },
    minimum: 10,
    maximum: 101,
  },
  data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: [
     { x: 100, y: 71 },
      { x: 200, y: 55},
      { x: 300, y: 50 },
      { x: 400, y: 65 },
      { x: 500, y: 95 },
      { x: 600, y: 68 },
      { x: 700, y: 28 },
      { x: 800, y: 34 },
      { x: 900, y: 14}
    ]
  }]
});

chart.render();
addStripLines(chart);

function addStripLines(chart) {
  var stripLines = [];

  for (var i = chart.axisY[0].minimum; i < chart.axisY[0].maximum;
    (i += 10)) {
    chart.axisY[0].addTo("stripLines", {
      value: i,
      label: i,
      labelPlacement: "outside",
      labelBackgroundColor: "transparent",
      labelFontColor: "black",
      color: "black"
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but on this example i put the minimum and maximum as an example , according to the real scenario the minimum and maximum could vary . for example : (0.1 to 1000) or (1 to 100000000)  all posibilities, so Is it possible to draw lines without providing minimum and maximum.

Comment: You can simply update `i += 10` according to your requirement (based on your range) and it should work fine.

Comment: Is it possible to give the lines without using minimum and maximum , since i have multiple curves on chart and its not possible to calculate the  minimum of all and maximum of all

Comment: Once the chart is rendered for the first time, even if you haven't given minimum and maximum you can access internally calculated minimum and maximum using [get() method](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/axis/get/)